# Using services to share state between controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to share 'state' between multiple controllers within my Angular app by using services. My code is below. The problem I'm running into is that the controller which initiates the change in state, through `vm.toggleStatus()`, is updated, but this state does not update in my other controller until I refresh the page.

controller1.js:

```
angular.module('gameApp')
  .controller('PlayerActionsController', PlayerActionsController);

PlayerActionsController.$inject = ['$routeParams', 'playersService'];

function PlayerActionsController($routeParams, playersService) {
  var vm = this;
  var playerId = $routeParams.playerId;

  var getplayerInfo = function() {
    playersService.getPlayerInfo({
      playerId: playerId
    }).$promise.then(function(player) {
      vm.player = player;
    });
  };

  var init = function() {
    getplayerInfo();
  };

  init();

  vm.toggleStatus = function() {
    playersService.toggleStatus({
      playerId: playerId
    }, {}).$promise.then(function() {
      getplayerInfo();
    });
  };
}
```

controller2.js:

```
angular.module('gameApp')
  .controller('HeaderController', HeaderController);

HeaderController.$inject = ['$routeParams', 'playersService'];

function HeaderController($routeParams, playersService) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.playerId = $routeParams.playerId;

  var getPlayerInfo = function() {
    playersService.getPlayerInfo({
      playerId: vm.playerId
    }).$promise.then(function(player) {
      vm.player = player;
    });
  };

  var init = function() {
    getPlayerInfo();
  };

  init();
}
```

players.service.js:

```
angular.module('gameApp')
  .factory('playersService', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
      var base = '/api/players/:playerId/';
      return $resource(base, {}, {
        getPlayerInfo: {method: 'GET', url: base + 'playerInfo'},
        toggleStatus: {method: 'PUT', url: base + 'toggleStatus'}
      });
    }]);
```

Comment: share your playerService implemntation

Comment: @Kram, added, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services do not push data to controllers, controllers need to either pull data from the service or listen to data changes.

What you probably want to do is update your service to emit an event when data changes and then have your controllers listed to those events and update when the change occurs. Example:

```
//service toggleStatus
toggleStatus = function(data) {
    ... what it currently does.


    $rootScope.$emit('StatusChangedEvent', newStatus);

    ... return promise;
}

// in your controllers

$rootScope.$on('StatusChangedEvent', function(evt, newStatus) {
    $scope.status = newStatus;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was under the impression it was possible to share state between controllers without messing with `$rootScope`.

Comment: Two way communication between controllers is typically done using services. However in order to push the changes to the controllers withouth having them pull it, $rootScope is usually used. You can have one-way communication between controllers via nested views, where the nested controller inherits the parent controller.